# How to know which field is dirty when using Angular SchemaForm?

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

how can I know which field is dirty when using Angular SchemaForm. Doesn't find any property indicates it in the debugger.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think davidlgj 's answer might help you with this. You'd have to replace the .$error in here with .$dirty

https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form/issues/376

Answer (score 0):

Each form field should have a $dirty flag attached to it. Let's say your form name is "MyForm" and your field name is "TestField". You can check if it's dirty by accessing "MyForm.TestField.$dirty".

Comment: I did try to find it during the debugger, but it's not there. the form is an array, are we talking about the schema.form (this is loaded from a json) or something else in a different thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize your model before rendering the page and then compare it with current model. It won't be that difficult to find differences between to models.